# setting android wear watch device owner

Tags: android, wear-os, kiosk-mode, device-owner

We are creating an app for android watch (in my case sony 3) that needs a kiosk mode.

Using

```
adb shell 
dpm set-device-owner com.example/.MyDeviveAdminReceiver
```

I get

```
Can't set package com.example as device owner.
```

using

```
db shell pm list features
```

I get

```
feature:reqGlEsVersion=0x20000
feature:android.hardware.bluetooth
feature:android.hardware.bluetooth_le
feature:android.hardware.faketouch
feature:android.hardware.location
feature:android.hardware.location.gps
feature:android.hardware.microphone
feature:android.hardware.screen.portrait
feature:android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer
feature:android.hardware.sensor.compass
feature:android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope
feature:android.hardware.sensor.light
feature:android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter
feature:android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch
feature:android.hardware.type.watch
feature:android.hardware.usb.accessory
feature:android.hardware.wifi
feature:android.software.home_screen
feature:android.software.live_wallpaper
feature:android.software.voice_recognizers
feature:com.sonymobile.watch
```

Does anyone has an experiance own creating a device owner app for android wear watch ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Taras, No, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this with wearables, but most of the times I got errors setting up DeviceOwner through `adb` was due to an existing google account on the device, meaning it is already provisioned. Device Owner setup requires the device to not be fully provisioned.

More on this: [How do you un-provision a device in order to set the Device Owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263988/how-do-you-un-provision-a-device-in-order-to-set-the-device-owner/39860462#39860462)