# Secure screen pinning as device owner

Tags: android, security, android-screen-pinning

I want to implement a secure kiosk mode to my app. Since Android 5.1 therefore the screen pinning  can be used. But every time i start the screen pinning I get a dialog which I don’t want and it’s possible to exit this kiosk mode by holding the back and the overview button.

Therefore I found out that these behaviours can’t be stoped by using the app as device owner.

Now my questions is:

What exactly is thise device owner oder a device admin app. How can I understand it?  It would be nice if someone can explain it in easy words.

And the second question:

How can I enable this and get my app working as device owner?

Answer (score 0):

DeviceOwner is a "state" an app can be set at during device provisioning.
It is not simple or easy to do, but once the app has been set as DeviceOwner, it can call some extra APIs not available to regular apps, even if those apps are set as DeviceAdmin.

- https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices
- [How do you un-provision a device in order to set the Device Owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30263988/1231880)